# Pool demolition

Tags: plumbing, pool, demolition

Approximately 15,000 gallon pool that I want to demolish and fill to have a regular backyard.

My concern is the established plumbing that is associated with the pool. What happens to it? I dont think they're removed but are the pipes filled? Or permanently closed?

Are there issues in the future such as cracking/collapsing of these pipes? Does water get in these pipes and affect the integrity of the foundation?

Basically whats done to the pipes to avoid issues in the future.

Sorry if it's a dumb question, I just want to be informed about this.

Answer (score 3):

Not a dumb question.   The last thing I would be worried about is the plumbing.

Before doing anything I would search your city's website to see if they have special orders for pool demos.  The only thing plumbing related would be a sewer disconnect permit (I kid you not - more than half the pools I have done).

Most cities could care less if you bury PVC and concrete - other stuff might need to be hauled away.   However...... the rest of the guidelines are made by the city if they have procedures and even if you think you are doing a better job, they don't care.   The inspector could even comment, well that way is actually better but not what the city wants - this attitude is normal for cities that rent inspectors.

Examples are some cities want up to 3' down removed, some it is 2', some 16".   Some want a certain kind of fill.   All are going to want you to punch holes in the bottom (sort of plumbing related) but each procedure will have a different "hole" requirement.

I probably have a reputation of doing a few things without permits.   I would NEVER fill a pool without a permit unless city gave me the OK.   It is just too much damn work to go back into and dig up and prove out that you did certain things.   I have never personally been there but have witnessed it more than once.